# Issue launching npm install on angular-seed project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, npm, angular-seed

I'm trying to launch 'npm install' on a cloned angular-seed scheleton but it returns me a couple of errors:

```
C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Folder\project\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
    gyp ERR! configure error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
    gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
    gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
    gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Folder\project\node_modules\bufferutil
    gyp ERR! node -v v5.9.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1
```

Anyone know how to solve it? I'm using a windows 10 x64 system.
Thank you in advance..

Comment: try it with a lower version of nodejs.  like 0.10~

Comment: you should install Python in your system